# Use variable in relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have some customfield functionality on my site where users can add custom fields to a model.

I've just found that if you enter data into one of the fields the same field won't show up for another model because of the way I get the empty fields for a model

```
public function Customfield()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customfield::class);
}

public function getEmptyCustomfields($model)
{
    return  $this->has('customfield', '<', 1)
                        ->select('customfieldslabels.id as label_id', 'customfieldslabels.datatype as datatype', 'customfieldslabels.label_name as label_name',
                                'customfieldslabels.customfield_tab_id as customfield_tab_id', 'customfieldstabs.name as name')
                        ->join('customfieldstabs', 'customfieldstabs.id', '=', 'customfieldslabels.customfield_tab_id')
                        ->where('customfieldstabs.model', '=', $model)
                        ->get();

}

public function getEmptyCustomfieldsByTab($tabIDm)
{
    return $this->has('customfield', '<', 1)->where('customfield_tab_id', '=', $tabID)->get();
}
```

This is what I had originally and I realised that if a label has a field that is assigned to another model then the relationship exists and won't return as empty for another model.

So I'm trying to also check against the model ID now but I'm not quite sure how to use the model ID while checking the relationship

```
public function Customfield()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customfield::class);
}

public function customfieldByModel($modelID)
{
    return $this->has('customfield' => function ($query) use ($modelID){
        $query->where('model_id', '=', $modelID);
    })->get();
}

public function getEmptyCustomfields($model, $modelID)
{
    return  $this->has($this->customfieldByModel($modelID), '<', 1)
                        ->select('customfieldslabels.id as label_id', 'customfieldslabels.datatype as datatype', 'customfieldslabels.label_name as label_name',
                                'customfieldslabels.customfield_tab_id as customfield_tab_id', 'customfieldstabs.name as name')
                        ->join('customfieldstabs', 'customfieldstabs.id', '=', 'customfieldslabels.customfield_tab_id')
                        ->where('customfieldstabs.model', '=', $model)
                        ->get();

}

public function getEmptyCustomfieldsByTab($tabIDm, $modelID)
{
    return $this->has($this->customfieldByModel($modelID), '<', 1)->where('customfield_tab_id', '=', $tabID)->get();
}
```

I would like to return empty fields for one model that they haven't been filled in for yet.

They return just find once there is data for a model assigned to a field as it doesn't need to check for empty fields anymore.

*UPDATE*

I've tried using a left join which I think will work but I can't get to the method because I get an error saying: 'The method name must be a string'

I changed this

```
public function getEmptyCustomfieldsByTab($tabID, $modelID)
{
    return $this->has($this->customfieldByModel($modelID), '<', 1)->where('customfield_tab_id', '=', $tabID)->get();
}
```

To this:

```
public function getEmptyCustomfieldsByTab($tabID, $modelID)
{
    return $this->has('customfieldbymodel', '<', 1)->where('customfield_tab_id', '=', $tabID)->get();
}
```

But now I can't send the $modelID as a parameter. Is it possible to sned a parameter while doing a has?

*MY SOLUTION*

I have created a protected variable on the model that just gets reassigned everytime.

```
protected $modelID;


public function customfieldByModel()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customfield::class)->where('model_id', '=', $this->modelID);
}

public function getEmptyCustomfields($model, $modelID)
{
    $this->modelID = $modelID;
    return  $this->has('customfieldByModel', '<', 1)
                        ->select('customfieldslabels.id as label_id', 'customfieldslabels.datatype as datatype', 'customfieldslabels.label_name as label_name',
                                'customfieldslabels.customfield_tab_id as customfield_tab_id', 'customfieldstabs.name as name')
                        ->join('customfieldstabs', 'customfieldstabs.id', '=', 'customfieldslabels.customfield_tab_id')
                        ->where('customfieldstabs.model', '=', $model)
                        ->get();

}

public function getEmptyCustomfieldsByTab($tabID, $modelID)
{
    $this->modelID = $modelID;
    return $this->has('customfieldByModel', '<', 1)->where('customfield_tab_id', '=', $tabID)->get();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Left Join, while I am not a Laravel user, most the time if you have data in one table and not in the related table, you use a left join which will populate the joined tables results with `NULL` values if the related record don't exist in that table.  I am not sure how Laravel's ORM (Eloquent) behaves, but I know a thing or 2 about ORMs